# What should a 'strict' confinement snapcraft be able to access without any plugs?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, snapcraft, snap

snapcraft 7.5.3 running on WSL2.

I created a very simple test snap package:

`snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: testsnap
base: core22 
version: '0.1' 
summary: testsnap
description: |
  test

grade: stable
confinement: strict

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: dump
    source: bin
    
apps:
  test:
    command: myecho
    plugs: []
```

As a test `myecho` reads the public key on the host machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $SNAP_REAL_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Since I don't have any plugs (eg. ssh-keys), I wouldn't have thought this should work.

However it happily outputs `ssh-rsa AAAAB3......`

As this is a test, I'm installing with `--dangerous` (which according to the docs I read shouldn't change confinement.)

```
 sudo snap install testsnap_0.1_amd64.snap --dangerous
```

Am I missing something simple? Or is this a WSL2 problem/limitation - if so I need to stop testing snaps on WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Snap uses `AppArmor` for [confinement](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) which is, at the time of writing, missing from WSL2 (as least by default)

Therefore testing snap packages using WSL2 isn't robust as confinement mistakes might be missed.

`snap debug confinement` can be run to check the snap environment. If it doesn't say `strict` then strict confinement isn't enforced. My WSL2 install says `partial`.